# Several vhosts with different SSL certs in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

First i would like to mention I have this setup working, what I am looking for is ideas for a different approach.

Right now I have 6 websites which use a different SSL cert on a single Amazon EC2, i am using the amazon LBS to get the request and then redirect to the proper port in the instansce so for example

a.com:8443
b.com:8444
c.com:8555

So I need a LB for a.com one for b.com one for c.com, thats fine and it works, but what i would like is to have a single listener, call it Amazon LB, HaProxy or anything which could redirect the request to the proper port something like this:

443 -> ### Listener ### 
           |
           |---> a.com:8443
           |
           |---> b.com:8444
           |
           |---> c.com:8445

In a few words, I would like to have a single entry point listening on port 443 which send the request to the proper port based on its hostname.

Answer (score 3):

If your domains share a common base, you may be able to use a wildcard SSL cert. Wildcard SSL certs only work for one subdomain level (unlink wildcard DNS). For example, *.example.com would work for a.example.com and b.example.com, but not example.com or a.b.example.com.

Otherwise, you may be stuck. The SSL handshake happens before any virtualhost negotiations. AWS treats IP's as valuable commodities. They don't offer more than one address per endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can do this with [nginx](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/basic#server_configuration) and multiple server{} blocks, each with their own listen port and SSL context.